# Fill a textBox with with values from a table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a form with some textBox and i want to fill one of them with a value from an SQL query.

the table is called `tbl-apartner` and i want to select every `mailadress` that matches with an `serviceid` (`sid2`).

```
SELECT [tbl-apartner].[EMail] FROM [tbl-apartner] WHERE [tbl-apartner].[SID] = sid2;
```

The output of that SELECT Statement is correct but im not able to fill a textBox with it.

My idea was to create a string with every mailadress that matches with the SID to use them as recipients for a mail.

I tried to use `dlookup(" [EMail]" ; "qry-apartner")`
But the output is only the first entry in my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write VBA function iterates through the query results and creates a single string to assign to your textbox. Depending on how your form behaves you can put this in the appropriate event, for example if your form opens once use the OnOpen, if `sid2` can be changed by the user use the AfterUpdate event of the relevant control, etc.

Sample code:

```
Dim ThisDB As DAO.Database
Set ThisDB = CurrentDb
Dim d As DAO.Recordset
Dim q As String
q = "SELECT [tbl-apartner].[EMail] FROM [tbl-apartner] WHERE [tbl-apartner].[SID] = " & sid2
Set d = ThisDB.OpenRecordset(q, dbOpenDynaset)
Dim Result As String
Result = ""
If d.EOF = False Or d.BOF = False Then
    d.MoveFirst
    Do While Not d.EOF
        If Result <> "" Then Result = Result & vbCrLf
        Result = Result & d!Email
        d.MoveNext
      Loop
  End If
d.Close
```

The above creates a new line for each email address. Replace vbCrLf with anything you want for example ", " will generate comma separated emails.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When i open that form im getting the error '3061'
Run-time error '3061'. Too few parameters. Expected 1. Set d = ThisDB.OpenRecordset(q, dbOpenDynaset)

Comment: I solved the problem. 

The Line 

Thanks for your help!

`q = "SELECT [tbl-apartner].[EMail] FROM [tbl-apartner] WHERE [tbl-apartner].[SID] = " & sid2` 

was not correct. 

    q = "SELECT [tbl-apartner].[EMail] FROM [tbl-apartner] WHERE [tbl-apartner].[SID] = " & "'" & sid2 & "'"

The difference is:     `= " & "'" & sid2 & "'"`

Comment: It is because you are using a text field for `sid2` instead of a numerical one, which is what my code was written for. Glad you figured it out as I was on vacation last week.